# API test + transactional rollback

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, integration-testing, spring-transactions

I have a test like this:

```
@Test
@Transactional
public void when_EnteredRegisteredProductionOrder_and_RegisteredStaffSignature_then_201_and_ProductionOrderRegistered() {
    //language=JSON
    String startProductionOrder = "{\n" +
            "  \"productionOrder\": \"1700281\",\n" +
            "  \"staffCodeSignature\": \"00000425\"\n" +
            "}";

    given()
            .body(startProductionOrder)
            .accept(ContentType.JSON)
            .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
            .when()
            .post(commandPath)
            .then().statusCode(201);


    ProductionOrder po = productionOrderRepo.findOneByCode("1700281");
    assertThat(po.getCode(), is("1700281"));
}
```

My intention is to test the REST API from start to end using restassured. As you can imagine each command, starting from the controller is annotated with @Transactional. The problem is that test does not rollback automatically. The debug log shows than (I removed many parts because it was too long to post):

```
DEBUG 14120 --- [           main] tractDirtiesContextTestExecutionListener : Before test method: context [DefaultTestContext@1dd02175 testClass = ProductionOrderStartLT, testInstance = com.demo.logbook.commandValidationLT.ProductionOrderStartLT@25359ed8, testMethod = when_EnteredRegisteredProductionOrder_and_RegisteredStaffSignature_then_201_and_ProductionOrderRegistered@ProductionOrderStartLT, testExcep
DEBUG 14120 --- [           main] t.a.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource : Adding transactional method 'com.demo.logbook.commandValidationLT.ProductionOrderStartLT.when_EnteredRegisteredProductionOrder_and_RegisteredStaffSignature_then_201_and_ProductionOrderRegistered' with attribute: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; ''
DEBUG 14120 --- [           main] t.c.t.TransactionalTestExecutionListener : Explicit transaction definition [PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; ''] found for test context [DefaultTestContext@1dd02175 testClass = ProductionOrderStartLT, testInstance = com.demo.logbook.commandValidationLT.ProductionOrderStartLT@25359ed8, testMethod = when_EnteredRegisteredProductionOrder_and_RegisteredStaffSignature_
DEBUG 14120 --- [           main] t.c.t.TransactionalTestExecutionListener : Retrieved @TransactionConfiguration [null] for test class [com.demo.logbook.commandValidationLT.ProductionOrderStartLT].
DEBUG 14120 --- [           main] t.c.t.TransactionalTestExecutionListener : Using TransactionConfigurationAttributes [TransactionConfigurationAttributes@4a5fab78 transactionManagerName = '', defaultRollback = true] for test class [com.demo.logbook.commandValidationLT.ProductionOrderStartLT].
DEBUG 14120 --- [           main] c.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate : Retrieved ApplicationContext from cache with key [[WebMergedContextConfiguration@31206beb testClass = ProductionOrderStartLT, locations = '{}', classes = '{class com.demo.logbook.ElogbookApplication}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{test}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{org.sp
DEBUG 14120 --- [           main] org.springframework.test.context.cache   : Spring test ApplicationContext cache statistics: [DefaultContextCache@c677d7e size = 1, maxSize = 32, parentContextCount = 0, hitCount = 1, missCount = 1]
DEBUG 14120 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'transactionManager'
DEBUG 14120 --- [           main] t.c.t.TransactionalTestExecutionListener : No method-level @Rollback override: using default rollback [true] for test context [DefaultTestContext@1dd02175 testClass = ProductionOrderStartLT, testInstance = com.demo.logbook.commandValidationLT.ProductionOrderStartLT@25359ed8, testMethod = when_EnteredRegisteredProductionOrder_and_RegisteredStaffSignature_then_201_and_Prod
DEBUG 14120 --- [           main] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Creating new transaction with name [com.demo.logbook.commandValidationLT.ProductionOrderStartLT.when_EnteredRegisteredProductionOrder_and_RegisteredStaffSignature_then_201_and_ProductionOrderRegistered]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; ''
DEBUG 14120 --- [           main] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Opened new EntityManager [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl@505a8582] for JPA transaction
DEBUG 14120 --- [           main] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Exposing JPA transaction as JDBC transaction [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect$HibernateConnectionHandle@465d1345]
 INFO 14120 --- [           main] o.s.t.c.transaction.TransactionContext   : Began transaction (1) for test context [DefaultTestContext@1dd02175 testClass = ProductionOrderStartLT, testInstance = com.demo.logbook.commandValidationLT.ProductionOrderStartLT@25359ed8, testMethod = when_EnteredRegisteredProductionOrder_and_RegisteredStaffSignature_then_201_and_ProductionOrderRegistered@ProductionOrderStartLT
DEBUG 14120 --- [           main] c.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate : Retrieved ApplicationContext from cache with key [[WebMergedContextConfiguration@31206beb testClass = ProductionOrderStartLT, locations = '{}', classes = '{class com.demo.logbook.ElogbookApplication}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{test}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{org.sp
DEBUG 14120 --- [           main] org.springframework.test.context.cache   : Spring test ApplicationContext cache statistics: [DefaultContextCache@c677d7e size = 1, maxSize = 32, parentContextCount = 0, hitCount = 2, missCount = 1]
DEBUG 14120 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoBeans'
DEBUG 14120 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
 INFO 14120 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
 INFO 14120 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
DEBUG 14120 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'multipartResolver'
DEBUG 14120 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Using MultipartResolver [org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardServletMultipartResolver@63880be9]
DEBUG 14120 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver'
DEBUG 14120 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor'
DEBUG 14120 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor'
DEBUG 14120 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor'
DEBUG 14120 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver'
DEBUG 14120 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Unable to locate LocaleResolver with name 'localeResolver': using default [org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver@560b484d]
DEBUG 14120 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.web.servlet.theme.FixedThemeResolver'
DEBUG 14120 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor'
DEBUG 14120 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor'
DEBUG 14120 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor'
DEBUG 14120 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.web.servlet.theme.FixedThemeResolver'
DEBUG 14120 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Unable to locate ThemeResolver with name 'themeResolver': using default [org.springframework.web.servlet.theme.FixedThemeResolver@5c57255c]
DEBUG 14120 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'requestMappingHandlerMapping'
DEBUG 14120 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'viewControllerHandlerMapping'
DEBUG 14120 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'beanNameHandlerMapping'
DEBUG 14120 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'resourceHandlerMapping'
DEBUG 14120 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'defaultServletHandlerMapping'
DEBUG 14120 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'faviconHandlerMapping'
DEBUG 14120 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'welcomePageHandlerMapping'
DEBUG 14120 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter'
DEBUG 14120 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'httpRequestHandlerAdapter'
DEBUG 14120 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'simpleControllerHandlerAdapter'
DEBUG 14120 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'errorAttributes'
DEBUG 14120 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'handlerExceptionResolver'
DEBUG 14120 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.web.servlet.view.DefaultRequestToViewNameTranslator'
DEBUG 14120 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor'
DEBUG 14120 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor'
DEBUG 14120 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor'
DEBUG 14120 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.web.servlet.view.DefaultRequestToViewNameTranslator'
DEBUG 14120 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Unable to locate RequestToViewNameTranslator with name 'viewNameTranslator': using default [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.DefaultRequestToViewNameTranslator@56aa150f]
DEBUG 14120 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'beanNameViewResolver'
DEBUG 14120 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'mvcViewResolver'
DEBUG 14120 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'defaultViewResolver'
DEBUG 14120 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'viewResolver'
DEBUG 14120 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.web.servlet.support.SessionFlashMapManager'
DEBUG 14120 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor'
DEBUG 14120 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor'
DEBUG 14120 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor'
DEBUG 14120 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.web.servlet.support.SessionFlashMapManager'
DEBUG 14120 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Unable to locate FlashMapManager with name 'flashMapManager': using default [org.springframework.web.servlet.support.SessionFlashMapManager@2c40b216]
DEBUG 14120 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Published WebApplicationContext of servlet 'dispatcherServlet' as ServletContext attribute with name [org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.CONTEXT.dispatcherServlet]
 INFO 14120 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 19 ms
DEBUG 14120 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Servlet 'dispatcherServlet' configured successfully
DEBUG 14120 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.s.b.w.f.OrderedRequestContextFilter    : Bound request context to thread: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@17b5f8f0
DEBUG 14120 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing POST request for [/commands/production/production-orders]
DEBUG 14120 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /commands/production/production-orders
DEBUG 14120 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Returning handler method [public void com.demo.logbook.commands.web.controllers.ProductionController.startProductionOrder(com.demo.logbook.commands.commands.productionOrder.StartProductionOrder)]
DEBUG 14120 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'productionController'
DEBUG 14120 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.j.s.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor : Opening JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
DEBUG 14120 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] m.m.a.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor : Read [class com.demo.logbook.commands.commands.productionOrder.StartProductionOrder] as "application/json;charset=UTF-8" with [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@ff21443]
DEBUG 14120 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Creating instance of bean 'org.hibernate.validator.internal.constraintvalidators.bv.NotNullValidator'
DEBUG 14120 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Finished creating instance of bean 'org.hibernate.validator.internal.constraintvalidators.bv.NotNullValidator'
DEBUG 14120 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'transactionManager'
DEBUG 14120 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Found thread-bound EntityManager [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl@2aa65d86] for JPA transaction
DEBUG 14120 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Creating new transaction with name [com.demo.logbook.commands.web.controllers.ProductionController.startProductionOrder]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; '',-java.lang.RuntimeException
DEBUG 14120 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Exposing JPA transaction as JDBC transaction [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect$HibernateConnectionHandle@63fa0a64]
DEBUG 14120 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] c.d.l.c.w.c.ProductionController         : Command received : StartProductionOrder{productionOrder='1700281'} SignedCommand{staffCodeSignature='00000425'}
 INFO 14120 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.h.h.i.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator  : HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
Hibernate: select eventtype0_.id as id1_17_, eventtype0_.name as name2_17_, eventtype0_.type as type3_17_ from events.event_type eventtype0_ where eventtype0_.name=?
Hibernate: select aggregate0_.aggregate_id as aggregat1_15_, aggregate0_.name as name2_15_ from events.aggregate aggregate0_ where aggregate0_.name=?
DEBUG 14120 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] c.d.l.event_store.services.EventStore    : Flushing event : Event
DEBUG 14120 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] stomAnnotationTransactionAttributeSource : Adding transactional method 'save' with attribute: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; ''
DEBUG 14120 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'transactionManager'
DEBUG 14120 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Found thread-bound EntityManager [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl@2aa65d86] for JPA transaction
DEBUG 14120 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Participating in existing transaction
Hibernate: select nextval ('hibernate_sequence')
DEBUG 14120 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] c.d.l.event_store.services.EventStore    : Event flushed : Event{event_id=31, correlation_id=e5901e3d-9cbf-4c53-bb8c-1fb1006328f8, data='{"transaction_id":"0c4cb269-32fc-422d-93a8-28d506911861","staffCodeSignature":"00000425","productionOrderCode":"1700281"}', version=1, eventType=com.demo.logbook.event_store.persistance.entities.EventType@34ef5c1b, aggregate=Aggregate{a
DEBUG 14120 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] c.d.l.c.w.c.ProductionController         : Publishing eventData : ProductionOrderStarted
DEBUG 14120 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] c.d.l.c.w.c.ProductionController         : Command success : StartProductionOrder{productionOrder='1700281'} SignedCommand{staffCodeSignature='00000425'}
DEBUG 14120 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'adminProjection'
DEBUG 14120 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] c.d.l.q.a.projection.AdminProjection     : Event received in admin module: ProductionOrderStarted
DEBUG 14120 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] c.d.l.q.a.s.AdminValidationService       : Validating event in admin module: ProductionOrderStarted
Hibernate: select count(production0_.product_order_id) as col_0_0_ from admin.production_order production0_ where production0_.code=?
Hibernate: select count(staff0_.reason_type_id) as col_0_0_ from admin.staff staff0_ where staff0_.code=?
DEBUG 14120 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] c.d.l.q.a.s.AdminValidationService       : Event validation successful in admin module: ProductionOrderStarted
DEBUG 14120 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] c.d.l.q.a.projection.AdminProjection     : Event processed successfully by admin module: ProductionOrderStarted
DEBUG 14120 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'productionProjection'
DEBUG 14120 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] c.d.l.q.p.p.ProductionProjection         : Event received in prod module: ProductionOrderStarted
DEBUG 14120 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] c.d.l.q.p.s.ProductionValidationService  : Validating event in prod module: ProductionOrderStarted
Hibernate: select production0_.transaction_id as transact1_20_, production0_.last_action_timestamp as last_act2_20_, production0_.code as code3_20_, production0_.product_code as product_4_20_, production0_.product_name as product_5_20_, production0_.work_center_code as work_cen6_20_, production0_.work_center_name as work_cen7_20_ from prod.production_order production0_ where production0_.code=?
2017-01-20 13:50:10.399 DEBUG 14120 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] c.d.l.q.p.s.ProductionValidationService  : Event validation successful in prod module: ProductionOrderStarted
Hibernate: select production0_.product_order_id as product_1_5_, production0_.code as code2_5_, production0_.product_id as product_3_5_, production0_.work_center_id as work_cen4_5_ from admin.production_order production0_ where production0_.code=?
Hibernate: select product0_.product_id as product_1_3_0_, product0_.box_size as box_size2_3_0_, product0_.code as code3_3_0_, product0_.container_size as containe4_3_0_, product0_.container_type as containe5_3_0_, product0_.description as descript6_3_0_, product0_.markezini_capacity as markezin7_3_0_, product0_.partena_capacity as partena_8_3_0_, product0_.product_category_id as product_9_3_0_, productca
Hibernate: select workcenter0_.work_center_id as work_cen1_13_0_, workcenter0_.code as code2_13_0_, workcenter0_.is_active as is_activ3_13_0_, workcenter0_.name as name4_13_0_, workcenter0_.wing_id as wing_id5_13_0_, wing1_.wing_id as wing_id1_12_1_, wing1_.name as name2_12_1_ from admin.work_center workcenter0_ left outer join admin.wing wing1_ on workcenter0_.wing_id=wing1_.wing_id where workcenter0_.w
DEBUG 14120 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] c.d.l.q.p.s.ProductionEventsService      : Flushing production order: ProductionOrder(super=TransactionalEntity(transaction_id=0c4cb269-32fc-422d-93a8-28d506911861, lastActionTimestamp=2017-01-20T13:50:10.425), code=1700281, workCenterCode=0032, workCenterName=SYFPAC A, productCode=0100100, productName=AMINOPHYLLINE 250MG PPAMP 10ML, reasonCodesList=null, inProcessContro
DEBUG 14120 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] stomAnnotationTransactionAttributeSource : Adding transactional method 'save' with attribute: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; ''
DEBUG 14120 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'transactionManager'
DEBUG 14120 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Found thread-bound EntityManager [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl@2aa65d86] for JPA transaction
DEBUG 14120 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Participating in existing transaction
Hibernate: select production0_.transaction_id as transact1_20_1_, production0_.last_action_timestamp as last_act2_20_1_, production0_.code as code3_20_1_, production0_.product_code as product_4_20_1_, production0_.product_name as product_5_20_1_, production0_.work_center_code as work_cen6_20_1_, production0_.work_center_name as work_cen7_20_1_, inprocessc1_.production_order_transaction_id as producti5_18
DEBUG 14120 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] c.d.l.q.p.s.ProductionEventsService      : Flushed production order: ProductionOrder(super=TransactionalEntity(transaction_id=0c4cb269-32fc-422d-93a8-28d506911861, lastActionTimestamp=2017-01-20T13:50:10.425), code=1700281, workCenterCode=0032, workCenterName=SYFPAC A, productCode=0100100, productName=AMINOPHYLLINE 250MG PPAMP 10ML, reasonCodesList=null, inProcessControl
DEBUG 14120 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] c.d.l.q.p.p.ProductionProjection         : Event processed successfully by prod module: ProductionOrderStarted
DEBUG 14120 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Initiating transaction commit
DEBUG 14120 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Committing JPA transaction on EntityManager [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl@2aa65d86]
Hibernate: insert into events.event (aggregate_id, correlation_id, data, event_type_id, time_created, version, event_id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into prod.production_order (last_action_timestamp, code, product_code, product_name, work_center_code, work_center_name, transaction_id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
DEBUG 14120 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Not closing pre-bound JPA EntityManager after transaction
DEBUG 14120 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
DEBUG 14120 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.j.s.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor : Closing JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
DEBUG 14120 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.s.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils    : Closing JPA EntityManager
DEBUG 14120 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Successfully completed request
DEBUG 14120 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.s.b.w.f.OrderedRequestContextFilter    : Cleared thread-bound request context: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@17b5f8f0
Hibernate: select production0_.transaction_id as transact1_20_, production0_.last_action_timestamp as last_act2_20_, production0_.code as code3_20_, production0_.product_code as product_4_20_, production0_.product_name as product_5_20_, production0_.work_center_code as work_cen6_20_, production0_.work_center_name as work_cen7_20_ from prod.production_order production0_ where production0_.code=?
DEBUG 14120 --- [           main] c.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate : Retrieved ApplicationContext from cache with key [[WebMergedContextConfiguration@31206beb testClass = ProductionOrderStartLT, locations = '{}', classes = '{class com.demo.logbook.ElogbookApplication}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{test}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{org.sp
DEBUG 14120 --- [           main] org.springframework.test.context.cache   : Spring test ApplicationContext cache statistics: [DefaultContextCache@c677d7e size = 1, maxSize = 32, parentContextCount = 0, hitCount = 3, missCount = 1]
DEBUG 14120 --- [           main] c.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate : Retrieved ApplicationContext from cache with key [[WebMergedContextConfiguration@31206beb testClass = ProductionOrderStartLT, locations = '{}', classes = '{class com.demo.logbook.ElogbookApplication}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{test}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{org.sp
DEBUG 14120 --- [           main] org.springframework.test.context.cache   : Spring test ApplicationContext cache statistics: [DefaultContextCache@c677d7e size = 1, maxSize = 32, parentContextCount = 0, hitCount = 4, missCount = 1]
DEBUG 14120 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoBeans'
DEBUG 14120 --- [           main] c.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate : Retrieved ApplicationContext from cache with key [[WebMergedContextConfiguration@31206beb testClass = ProductionOrderStartLT, locations = '{}', classes = '{class com.demo.logbook.ElogbookApplication}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{test}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{org.sp
DEBUG 14120 --- [           main] org.springframework.test.context.cache   : Spring test ApplicationContext cache statistics: [DefaultContextCache@c677d7e size = 1, maxSize = 32, parentContextCount = 0, hitCount = 5, missCount = 1]
DEBUG 14120 --- [           main] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Initiating transaction rollback
DEBUG 14120 --- [           main] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Rolling back JPA transaction on EntityManager [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl@505a8582]
DEBUG 14120 --- [           main] o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager        : Closing JPA EntityManager [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl@505a8582] after transaction
DEBUG 14120 --- [           main] o.s.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils    : Closing JPA EntityManager
 INFO 14120 --- [           main] o.s.t.c.transaction.TransactionContext   : Rolled back transaction for test context [DefaultTestContext@1dd02175 testClass = ProductionOrderStartLT, testInstance = com.demo.logbook.commandValidationLT.ProductionOrderStartLT@25359ed8, testMethod = when_EnteredRegisteredProductionOrder_and_RegisteredStaffSignature_then_201_and_ProductionOrderRegistered@ProductionOrderStart
DEBUG 14120 --- [           main] tractDirtiesContextTestExecutionListener : After test method: context [DefaultTestContext@1dd02175 testClass = ProductionOrderStartLT, testInstance = com.demo.logbook.commandValidationLT.ProductionOrderStartLT@25359ed8, testMethod = when_EnteredRegisteredProductionOrder_and_RegisteredStaffSignature_then_201_and_ProductionOrderRegistered@ProductionOrderStartLT, testExcept
```

Which seems that a new appplication context (and tread is used). How can I accomplish the above task? Is it the only way to use @AfterTranscation and clean my database for each test?

Comment: Currently I use @Sql with ExecutionPhase.AFTER_TEST_METHOD to truncate tables after each test. But this won't work if I try the run them in parallel. So I think the transaction rollback is still useful (and faster).

Comment: did you find a solution for this?

Comment: not...I guess I will revisit it after my deadlines

Answer (score 6):

`@Transactional` only works within the same thread, and as such the rollback provided by Spring will only work on the objects that were persisted on the thread where the transaction was started.

Your rest-assured test will perform an integration test and will hit your Spring context on another thread. So although your rest-assured test would be able to see the objects persisted in your test setup, Spring will never be able to cleanup resources persisted in your rest-assured test automatically.

The only way to tackle this is to delete the entities yourself in your test (Using an Junit Rule, or cleaning up any state in your test setup).

Answer (score 1):

I've been banging my head against this problem, and have managed to find a workaround for it. The problem is indeed caused by the fact that the JUnit test runs in a different thread as the embedded servlet container. This means that two transactions and database connections are opened, unaware of each other. The fix is to propagate the transaction that was opened in the JUnit test to the servlet container (using a Filter):

```
@Transactional
public class MyTest {
    private static final String[] FIELD_NAMES = {"resources", "synchronizations", "currentTransactionName", "currentTransactionReadOnly", "currentTransactionIsolationLevel", "actualTransactionActive"};
    private static final Field[] FIELDS = new Field[FIELD_NAMES.length];
    private static final Object[] FIELD_VALUES = new Object[FIELD_NAMES.length];

    @Before
    public void copyTransactionThreadLocals() {
        for (int i=0; i<FIELD_NAMES.length; i++) {
            Field field = ReflectionUtils.findField(TransactionSynchronizationManager.class,FIELD_NAMES[i]);
            field.setAccessible(true);
            FIELD_VALUES[i] = ((ThreadLocal)ReflectionUtils.getField(field,null)).get();
            FIELDS[i] = field;
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    static class Config {
        @Bean
        public Filter transactionFilter() {
            return new OncePerRequestFilter() {
                @Override
                protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
                    for (int i=0; i<FIELD_NAMES.length; i++) {
                        ((ThreadLocal)ReflectionUtils.getField(FIELDS[i],null)).set(FIELD_VALUES[i]);
                    }
                    filterChain.doFilter(request,response);
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Please be aware that the above code is a hack that uses reflection to copy inaccessible static fields.

Answer (score 1):

With these integration tests, Spring is reusing its test context and the old transaction can stick around and cause tests to fail in weird ways due to state from previous tests. If you see tests that pass when run by themselves fail when run together, then annotate the tests with @DirtiesContext. This lets Spring know it should discard the test context instead of reusing it.